# how to use API in Vb net

Tags: vb.net

What is the best way to issue a http get in VB.net? I want to get the result of a request like

http://89.36.220.56/api.php?photo=urlphoto&point=numberlikes&socks=proxy

- Photo = URL Photo
- Point = Number
- Socks = Proxy

Comment: My question, **why promote illegal likes on photos**? What does this solve and also I'm sure Instagram wouldn't like this :)

Answer (score -1):

```
    Dim url = "http://89.36.220.56/api.php?photo=urlphoto&point=numberlikes&socks=proxy"
    Dim request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
    Dim response = request.GetResponse()
    Dim receiveStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim readStream As New StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8)
    Dim data = readStream.ReadToEnd()
    response.Close()
    readStream.Close()
```